# How will DApps work on Cardano?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, decentralized-applications

This may been too broad of a question but I was hoping to ask a few specific questions here rather than over multiple questions. I don't think DApps are available yet but I'm sure people have started preparing for them.

Will we need to learn Plutus to make DApps and how easily can you transition from Solidity to Plutus programming? I'm also wondering what incentive there is to create and launch a DApp on Cardano over Ethereum?

If anyone could answer these question and perhaps point me in the direction of places to find more resources that would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a plan to port Solidity to Cardano. I believe there's even a running prototype. There are also plans for a cross-compiler that would transform most popular languages into Plutus. But personally, if you intend to jump in with both feet, I think it's worth learning the native language. For help getting started, look for the Plutus Pioneer lecture videos.

I see two major advantages in adopting Cardano today.

1. Transaction fees are demonstrably and vastly cheaper than Ethereum which is attractive to you and your end users.
2. Striking early, now, gives you a first-mover advantage to a captivated audience.

Comment: Can you elaborate on transaction fees?

Answer (score 4):

Charles Hoskinson [mentioned](https://youtu.be/nwMZFGHo1p4?t=1345) that first Solidity (the Ethereum smart contracts) will be available in the testnet of Cardano and in the future they will be incorporated as sidechain once the sidechains implementation is in production.
More on Smart Contracts on Cardano check [this video](https://youtu.be/k8a6tX53YPs).

Answer (score 2):

Is your question how dApps will work or how smart contracts? So far I only see (incomplete) answers for smart contracts, given there is already development in smart contracts including Plutus and Marlowe.

Given that there is already amazing stuff that can be done with the recent releases on the Cardano (test and main) network (TX with metadata, Native tokens including NFTs, Hydra), you can start already building apps (dApps) that take advantage of these.

dApps can already be built with the various libs and tooling being released.
https://docs.cardano.org/getting-started/integrating-with-third-parties
You can manage wallets, accounts and talk to your own Cardano node(s). There are multiple endpoints already ready in these libraries including GraphQL, Rossetta, Wallets, etc.
The developer docs were just released and they look fantastic. https://docs.cardano.org/